# Hit a key to "move and resize active window"

Tags: macos, display

I'd like to bind a key to an action that "takes the active windows and moves it to screen S, coordinates X,Y resizes it W,H". The S,X,Y,W,H variables can be hard-coded.

I don't know where to look for, is this doable? Do I need to mess with ActionScript or create an app or what?

(I'm a programmer but I don't know anything about programming/scripting for OS X)

**Update**:

I found out [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) which happily [does exactly that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEDdv.jpg):

- a single keystroke, to resize the active window to a pixel specified layout

Now, while I'm happy about that, I'd like to know if there was a program which allowed **more than one layout** (SizeUp allows only one if I'm not mistaken). It would still have to be single-keystroke and possible to insert pixel precise values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

I use a little app called [Divvy](http://www.mizage.com/divvy/) to do this. You can set up a global hotkey to bring up Divvy. And then within Divvy you can set up hotkeys that will snap the current window to a specific location and a specific size. It's great for quickly doing 2-up Finder windows for copying things back and forth. Or a Finder window on the left and a CyberDuck window on the right for remote copies. One of those apps that, when it's not on a Mac, will make it feel a little bit broken.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to carve Divvy into what I really wanted (single-key, pixel explicit), but trying to do that I stumbled upon SizeUp, which does exactly that!

Comment: Edited the question to ask if I can do the same thing but with more than one layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
set a to path to frontmost application as text
tell application "Finder"
    set {0, 0, dtw, dth} to bounds of window of desktop
end tell
try
    tell application a to tell window 1
        set bounds to {0, 22, dtw / 2, dth}
    end tell
end try
```

The behavior with multiple displays is pretty confusing: [Daring Fireball: Getting the Size of Your Display With AppleScript, the Lazy Way](http://daringfireball.net/2006/12/display_size_applescript_the_lazy_way).

You can assign a shortcut for running it with for example FastScripts, Apptivate, Quicksilver or by making a service with Automator.