# Edge resizing on Mac Finder windows?

Tags: windows, window-manager, display

One of the few ways I think Windows beats the Mac is in letting the user resize a window from any edge or corner, not just from the bottom-right corner.

I haven't found any software that enables this functionality on the Mac. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)

Comment: @mankoff: I checked that before I asked my question and it didn't seem to deal specifically with my issue. Now that I've learned about Afloat thanks to Aaron Lake I see that this specific feature is buried at the bottom of a longer list of features in the Afloat entry. Do what you want regarding closing this question, but my question and that one are not duplicative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/), a free product by Infinite Labs, will let you resize a window by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + Right Click.  Divvy would also work, but Afloat is a free solution.

Comment: I tried Afloat, and it was okay; however, I then tried Flexiglass, and I prefer it. However, it does cost money ($8 on App Store), whereas Afloat is free...

Answer (score 10):

One of the new features that arrived in Mac OS X 10.7 Lion is the ability to [resize a window from any edge](http://www.doobybrain.com/2011/02/25/mac-os-x-lion-will-allow-window-resizing-from-any-side/).

Answer (score 0):

I know you are looking specifically for edge resizing, but one option would be to use software that lets you set up predefined window sizes/locations that you can apply to a window.

For example, [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) lets you create presets or drag your mouse against a small grid to locate the window.  I'm just getting started with it but it seems useful.

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not answer the OP's actual question (namely, resizing from window edges), since Afloat ended up been mentioned, I wanted to point out another app similar in purpose to Afloat is Zooom/2.  It has the advantage of letting you choose the key bindings for resize (and other) behaviors it implements.  It's not free, but it works.  (I've used both Zooom/2 and Afloat, and have no ties whatsoever to any of the developers.)