# Gather all windows of an app to one screen

Tags: display

I have a two-monitor setup. I use one monitor as "primary" and other as "Reference" i.e I do active work using primary monitor and the secondary monitor has the windows that I refer to while doing my work. Over a period of time, multiple windows of the same app (Outlook, Excel, Word, PyCharm, etc.) end up distributed on different windows.

I need a shortcut/ third party app which on a keystroke or option from a menu that "gathers" all the windows that belong to the current active app into a single screen (primary screen or an option to select which screen).

Essentially I need the functionality of the "Gather Windows" option present in the Display Preference extended to all apps. I looked at this question: [Trigger 'Gather Windows' programmatically (or other quick way)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12769/trigger-gather-windows-programmatically-or-other-quick-way) but that operates only on Display Preference window.

If not possible out of the box, third party apps are fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

A utility that groups open windows in Mac OS X is called Mission Control. With it, you can also create separate Spaces and organize your open windows into Spaces by simply dragging them. The article below gives great visual examples.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204100

Comment: Yes but that's a manual solution. We need a single "keystroke" or "click"

Comment: More specifically (at least in my case): I have several Spaces, a lot of Chrome windows in a couple of them, and I'd like to yank certain other apps into a different Space without having to pick them out of each other space.