# Resizing/moving windows with keypress and mouse in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, window-manager

A few years ago I remember a friend using an application in Ubuntu that made window management extremely easy. If you wanted to move the active window, you would press a key and drag the window by clicking anywhere on the window. If you wanted to resize the active window (proportionally), you would press a key and turn the wheel. I think this is very intuitive way to resize and move a window.

Are there any free applications for Mac OS X that can utilize similar mechanics?

Comment: Duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) does moving and resizing as explained, and does more than that. I really loved this application.

Comment: COOL. +1 for this app. Thanx.

Comment: Already installed Afloat. It is really cool. ctrl-cmd-scroll ---> transparency change is fantastic. :)

Answer (score 2):

Free:

- [BetterTouchTool](http://boastr.de)

  - Primarily used for mapping actions to gestures
- [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat)

  - SIMBL plugin

Commercial:

- [Zooom2](http://coderage-software.com)

  - Allows using fn as a modifier
  - Snap to screen edges and other elements
- [MondoMouse](http://atomicbird.com/mondomouse)
- [Flexiglass](http://nulana.com/flexiglass)

  - Also other window management features, like split screen shortcuts
- [BetterSnapTool](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12)
- [NuKit](http://nulana.com/nukit)
- [HyperDock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/)

  - Also Aero snap like functionality

Answer (score -2):

Not exactly what you want but:

- zooming is build-in OS X. Go to System preferences -> Mouse  and check "Zoom while scroll wheel while holding Controll". After this you can zoom any part of the screen with CTRL+scrollwheel. It is not an "window zoom" but screen zoom - but sometimes helpful.

Comment: care the down-voter comment the down-vote?

Comment: The question was about moving or resizing windows, not zooming the screen.