# Dual screens with different resolutions

Tags: screen

I have my MBP connected to another screen with a smaller resolution. Thus when I want to move a window on the other screen, I have to resize it first to that it fits, then I can make it full screen again.

Is there a more convenient way to do that ?

Comment: Take a look at the different alternatives we've found so far in AskDifferent: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9659/115

Comment: I do this all the time by just moving the window to the other screen and hitting "+" button. Recently, this method started acting funny but then a reboot solved it.  Is this not working for you?  I have OS X 10.8.3 and MBP late edition 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use a window manager. I use **[Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/)** ([$14](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/divvy/id413857545?mt=12&ls=1)), which lets me press a one keyboard shortcut to move a window to the other monitor and resize it to full-screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend a similar product [Size Up](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) which lets you move and resize windows with keyboard shortcuts.  Its $13 nagware, so free if you don't mind it pestering you occasionally.