# How do I maximize a window vertically?

Tags: terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)

Is there some keyboard shortcut, mouse gesture, or add-on I can install that will allow me to maximize terminal windows vertically?

When I press the green button on a terminal, it maximizes vertically and horizontally. I want a way to maximize vertically only.

Comment: A wide array of window manipulation tools are listed here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The "duplicate" post mentions nothing about vertically maximizing a window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a stock feature of the OS, but you might have some luck with third-party add-on [BetterSnapTool](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12), which mimics Windows Aero Snap features.

Answer (score 2):

Another 3rd party program you may be interested in is [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/).  Divvy is a window management tool that allows you to very easily resize windows.  You can set shortcut keys to have predefined window sizes and make the active window fit to that predefined size.