# Resize and position windows using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)

I want to be able to resize and move a window without using a mouse.

Recently I found [shiftit](http://code.google.com/p/shiftit/), which is 80% what I need. The only thing it is missing is the window resize. And it is not updated since 2010 :( .

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: You may find something suitable in the answers to [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x). There are at least a few that can use keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered Moom http://manytricks.com/moom/ or MercuryMover http://www.heliumfoot.com/mercurymover/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I use and love Divvy.  You can define grid layouts and hotkeys to invoke them.

http://mizage.com/divvy/