# Is there a keyboard shortcut to move a window from one monitor to another?

Tags: macos, keyboard, display, window-manager

Is there a free app that I can use to move a window from one monitor to the other monitor (assuming only two monitors) via the keyboard? I shouldn't have to use the mouse at all (e.g., for selecting the window or the monitor, or for dragging).

I know this can be done in Linux using compiz; I'm surprised there isn't a (free) option for OS X.

Comment: Answered a similar question here: https://superuser.com/a/1515866/1128269

Answer (score 145, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Spectacle is no longer maintaned.  The website forwards users to Rectangle, see [Jack's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379697/287) or https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle/releases.

---

I just tried [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com), great app and it's free.

This is what it can do with the selected group of windows.

[image]

You need to activate accessibility support.

System Preferences > Accessibility > Enable access for assisted devices

As per comments: The accessibility option in Mavericks is now in

System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility

[image]

[image]

Comment: Worked for me without having to enable assistive devices in accessibility options.

Comment: With OS X Mavericks, the option to enable access for assistive devices has moved to System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Privacy -> Accessibility, where you will see Spectacle listed and can allow it to control your computer.

Comment: To specifically identity the shortcut, Spectacle use the shortcuts, ⌃⌥⌘← &   ⌃⌥⌘→ to alternate windows to each display.

Comment: I use Spectacle already, so I tried this... unfortunately the first thing I tried (my own Java / OpenGL app)

Comment: it's awesome and can do many cool things that win7+ is able to do which I missed, BUT I couldn't make it do what the original question is asking - move the window across monitors. :(

Comment: [Spectacle](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbvtt4g6tf93wux/spectacle_move_monitor.png) now allows you to do this (click link for image).

Comment: Works well. Although a way to move windows from one screen(not monitor) to other could be helpful. Works for the question asked.

Comment: If the window is maximized, **spectacle** will not keep it maximized in the new monitor, so this is not a good solution IMO. **shiftlt**, mentioned in [Wilfred Springer's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107576/270659), keeps the window maximized, so to me it seems to be the best solution

Comment: Spectacle is no longer maintained - check out [Rectangle App](https://rectangleapp.com/) instead, the replacement their team recommends: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379697/359074

Comment: Spectacle works on Catalina, but when a window is maximised it will not move it to another screen. So anyway I have to use the mouse to do it :(

Comment: For me, using Rectangle, the "Next Display" & "Previous Display" seem to be disabled (greyed out in the dropdown menu). Other shortcuts are working fine. Any hints on why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rectangle is a no go for me. It does not move windows from one monitor to another right, nor is it able to move it to the next desktop.

Answer (score 190):

There is yet another option that's completely free and requires no third-party app. Be aware that I've only tested this on MacOS latest version Catalina (as of now). For other OS versions see [Create keyboard shortcuts for apps on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/10.15/mac/10.15)

1. Go to System Preferences
2. Select Keyboard and then the Shortcuts tab
3. Then on the list that appears select App Shortcuts
4. Add new shortcuts like this:

   - Click on the plus sign to add a new one, the Menu Title field has to match **exactly** the text that appears on the Window menu in every application: "Move to DISPLAY NAME" (To find the text just open the Window menu on any application)
   - Finally on the Keyboard Shortcut field enter the shortcut you'd like to use
   - Add as many shortcuts as you need to move any window between your displays!

[image]

Comment: This should be the new correct answer. Also it should be noted, if you have multiple monitors of the same brand and model, it will toggle between them so you only need one shortcut for both/all screens

Comment: works like a charm, this should be the correct answer. [volni](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/12501/volni)

Comment: Yay! I'm just playing around now with my windows back and forth :D Joy! Thanks! Definitely the correct answer.

Comment: @AtomRiot I respectfully disagree. While it's a nice option, it doesn't work well for multiple monitors (moving a window to the "right" monitor is useful in BTT). Additionally, this moves the window to a strange location on the monitor. BTT can both center the window on the other monitor, or make it fullscreen on the other monitor, both of which are useful options to have.

Comment: `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType` For external monitors this command will list displays (after the GPU it is attached to).

Comment: "Move to Built-in Retina Display" for easy copy-paste

Comment: I agree with @SkeletonBow - BTT allows you to cycle between any number of monitors with any names with no need to update the respective commands. The only minor disadvantage of the BTT technique is that it doesn't move the window in an animated fashion.

Comment: Brilliant! Click on "Window" in the menu of any app, move the app to each display, look for "Move to Built-in Retina Display" (as above), or "Move to C27F390", for example.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for apps that have a "Window → Move" menu option. Not as convenient as the MS Windows "Windows Key + Shift + Right arrow".

Comment: This solution works perfectly. I configured two shortcut same as MS Windows: CMD + Swift + Left/Right arrow.

Comment: How did you know this would work? What design pattern from Apple made you figure this out?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'm using Mojave

Comment: does not work if the Window is maximised.

Comment: This works well for non-maximimized windows (if it's not working for you, try closing the Keyboard preferences for the hotkey to take effect). It doesn't work for maximized windows as the "Window > Move to..." options are disabled. [11.6 Big Sur]

Comment: Thank you! and YES! I'm also playing with my windows now ;'DD
It's working for my maximized windows (11.6 Big Sur). Does NOT work for FULL SCREEN windows. (Maximize is different from full screen on mac).
You can maximize windows without going Full Screen: double-click toolbar (top bar) of any window.
I used Opt+Ctrl+UP, Opt+Ctrl+DOWN (my screens are arranged vertically).

Comment: Definitely the correct answer. And 3rd party apps (like Magnet) can only move non-maximized windows as well; those apps are just wrappers of functionality like what is provided natively in System Preferences. You just have to poke around.

Comment: I'm not a Mac fan but this worked great, thank you!!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work on windows that are zoomed (in the fullscreen mode).

Comment: Can't get this work with Gigabyte monitors. Is there any way to simply set a command to cycle an app through ALL displays?

Comment: For me it took 1-2 minutes to start working after I add shortcut

Comment: Note: I tested it In the Italian version of MacOS and you have to use the proper translation of the move command instead of using the English one Move, so it's seems to be language dependent depending on which software you re using; Eg: Xcode is English only and it displays "Move to Buil in retina display" while pages which is Italian displays "Sposta su Monitor Retina integrato" in italian).

Comment: I've found it to be pretty picky about the shortcuts it will accept. Rectangle is still far less hassle, unfortunately.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either

Answer (score 59):

I ended up using [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) to do this. Overall I found it to be the most configurable. Here is a screenshot of my configuration, whereas <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> moves a window to the next monitor.

If you have a 3 monitor setup (2 external monitors and the Mac monitor), you can set up the "Move Window to Next Monitor" to the ***right*** by doing the following:

1. set up a new shortcut, specify "Move Window to Next Monitor" as the Predefined Action
2. click Attach Additional Action and *again* specify "Move Window to Next Monitor" as the action
3. Voila, you can now move a window to the monitor on the right (a little hacky I know, but it works until the developer of BTT updates the app)

[image: BetterTouchTool keyboard configuration]

The only shortcoming of BetterTouchTool is poor Lion support (not all features are available) but it is available as an alpha release. This specific keyboard shortcut should work fine in Lion with the stable version, I reckon.

Comment: Oh, and it's freeware.

Comment: I've gotten rid of Moom (almost ran out of trial clicks) and am using it BTT now. I feel like BTT can be slimmed down and polished but it does move windows from one monitor to another for free, so I can't complain.

Comment: It's not freeware now. Donationware.

Comment: As far as I could tell, BTT is no longer free (there's a free trial though)

Comment: It's 2019 this answer suggested a commercial solution, use the other A'er if you'd rather not have to pay for an app to do something that the OS should prob. be doing for you for free.

Comment: Heh, great trick with moving the window twice. <3

Answer (score 37):

Check out [Rectangle App](https://rectangleapp.com/). It's free, open-source, and is billed as the spiritual successor to the once brilliant (but sadly, no-longer-maintained) Spectacle.

You can install Rectangle App either via their website or with Homebrew: `brew install --cask rectangle`

[image]

Comment: not yet there https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle/issues/199

Comment: Awesome tool. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: the shortcut to move a window a screen to the left/right is ⌃+⌥+⌘+←/→

Comment: does not work in fullscreen mode

Comment: Shortcut on Rectangle: `⌃⌥⌘ + ←/→` - move to next/prev display.

Answer (score 21):

[Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) can do this. It is [not free](http://itunes.apple.com/app/moom/id419330170?mt=12), but Moom is a fantastic window management app. It lets you assign keyboard shortcuts to a variety of windows movements (including move to other display) and gives you an overlay of the OS X standard window controls.

Here are some *screenshots*:

[image: mouse usage]
[image: keyboard usage]

Here is a [list of window management apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x) from another AskDifferent post, [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x). The only free option is [Shiftit](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt), and I'm not sure if it offers the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: I've been using ShiftIt for arranging windows within the same monitor. It's an excellent tool for that. However, it offers no move-to-other-display functionality.

Comment: I'd check out Moom then. I know you wanted a free app, but it's quite inexpensive compared to many other Mac window managers. Plus, the overlay they designed for close/min/maximize buttons is so spiffy that they deserve the $5. :)

Comment: @ArtemShnayder no longer true, ver 1.6 released this year now supports it; check out [@WilfredSpringer 's answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107576/58743)

Comment: As far as I can tell, Moom is the only one that will let you move a window to the display in a given direction (up, down, left, right).  The others just have "next display".

Answer (score 21):

macOS Big Sur has built-in tool to do this. Press/click on the green button on top of a window for a second to get a dropdown with options for the current windows.

[image]

Comment: There is no keyboard shortcut for this though, right?

Comment: Yes but I figure it's worth pointing out that now this window moving to other display thing is baked in the OS

Comment: It's not a Big Sur Specific, it's been there for a couple of earlier versions.

Comment: is there a way to do this without the mouse being used on a display? I just cracked my macbook display and am trying to move windows over from there to an external monitor to save some work but can't exactly see what I'm doing.

Comment: Actually, it looks like from the Dock you can right click an app, then select `Options`, then select `Desktop on Display 1` or `Desktop on Display 2`, etc.

Answer (score 16):

I was using [ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt) for ages.

However, I thought it didn't support dealing with multiple displays, so I started looking for alternatives. I installed [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/), and changed the key bindings to be the same as ShiftIt's.

Then, when I wanted to deinstall ShiftIt, I found out it *does* actually support moving windows to different screens, using: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

So I uninstalled Spectacles; still a happy ShiftIt user.

Comment: Default for me was Ctrl+Option+Command+Space

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It works.

Comment: If the window is maximized, **shiftlt** will keep it maximized in the next display, contrary to **spectacle**. Best solution IMO :)

Comment: ShiftIt won! Spectacle is not able to un-zoom a window. It has an option called `Fullscreen`, that's actually not MacOS' fullscreen (zoom), but maximize. And when a window is in the fullscreen (zoomed) mode, Spactacle is unable to control it at all. But ShiftIt is able to un-zoom it and then it's possible to move it to another display.

Answer (score 16):

Just wanted to mention that there's a setting in `System Preferences > Mission Control` called **"Group windows by application"** that shows the app icons and allows you to drag the icon into another desktop/monitor. It's amazing for apps that have 10+ windows.

Comment: This only seems to work though if all windows are already on the same space (not if they are distributed between spaces).

Answer (score 13):

FYI, Magnet, the popular window placement/sizing application, has "Next Display" and "Previous Display" shortcuts right out of the box, at least in version 2.1 (Feb 14, 2017).

[Magnet on the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/magnet/id441258766)

[Magnet's Website](http://magnet.crowdcafe.com/)

Comment: Magnet is nice. If they only would have a nicer menu bar icon it would be perfect.

Answer (score 6):

- [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/)
- [Moom](http://target.georiot.com/Proxy.ashx?grid=598&GR_URL=http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=419330170%26mt=12)
- [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/)
- [Window Mover](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/window-mover/id412418002?mt=12)
- [BetterSnapTool](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12)
- [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net)

Comment: BTT is no longer free

Comment: I would add [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/) to this list.

Answer (score 6):

BetterSnapTool also has this feature (as a shortcut). I think it was a free app, and its been a great one.

There is a shortcut where you can maximize the window in the next screen (among other shortcuts or ways of doing this). See the screenshot of the related shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: wish they had "full screen on next monitor" too!

Comment: it is called BetterTouchTool the free version and the option is found under window resize and move

Comment: As far as I could tell, BTT is no longer free (there's a free trial though)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to install any third-party software, you can switch the current window to any monitor by going to the following menu

Window -> Select the monitor / display name

If the menu is not enabled,
Click on the green button [image], to come out of full screen to enable the below menu  then click,

Window -> Select the monitor / display name

Also after coming off of full screen mode, if you mouse over on the green button, you can get a pop-up with the option to "move to desired screen", click on it to move it to the desired screen.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: This must be the official answer as this is the easiest thing to do.

Comment: @UpulDoluweera This can't be the official answer since it's not a keyboard shortcut. The question was about keyboard shortcuts only. But, still useful.

Answer (score 5):

building on the answer above, using native Mac controls. There is a menu item that you can use to move apps between screens. It does **not** have a keyboard shortcut though which is what I was looking for. But there's hope! Using keyboard shortcuts, you can create your own shortcuts to move windows between screens. Here's how:

**Find the name of the menu item you want to create a shortcut for:**
Click Window in any application and look for a menu item that says "Move to "

**Create a keyboard shortcut to do it:**
Open keyboard settings (System preferences -> Keyboard).
Choose "App Shortcuts".
Click + to create a new shortcut.
Set Application to "All Applications".
Set Menu Title to **exactly** the menu item wording you found above
Set the keyboard shortcut you want to use

If you did this successfully, you should now see the shortcut appear next to the menu item and using your keyboard should moved the window to the other screen.

NOTES:
You will need to do the steps above to create a shortcut for each screen you have. To get the screen names, you'll need to move applications to each screen and see what the menu item changes to and then create a shortcut for that screen.

When I first did this, the shortcut didn't work. I suspect I chose a keyboard shortcut that was already in use somewhere else.  I fixed this by using the Command, Option, and Control buttons as part of the shortcut

This works for almost every app I have but one app doesn't support this because it doesn't have the menu item

Comment: This should be the selected answer, works perfectly!

Comment: What do you mean by "the answer above"? The order answers are displayed in can change based on the chosen sorting mechanism, votes on the answers themselves changing, and new answers coming in. In general, answers should stand on their own; if you do refer to another answer, you should summarize/quote the relevant parts of that answer in your own answer in case that answer is edited, deleted, or moved.

Comment: This works, but not with Firefox for some reason on macOS 13 (and even when it does work with, say Chrome, it seems buggy, probably a Ventura problem)

Answer (score 1):

This open source app is simple easy to use and free. It will accomplish what you need.

https://www.spectacleapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Wellington Felix's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382597), with [the same caveat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-a-window-from-one-monitor-to-another/382597#comment547370_382597) that it only  works for apps that have a "Window → Move" option.

1. Activate Help menu: <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd>
2. Search for `Move to <display name>`
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

or

1. Activate Help menu: <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd>
2. Go to Window menu: <kbd>←</kbd>
3. Use <kbd>m</kbd> and arrow keys to select desired display
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool for more advanced users called [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/). With this, you can achieve a lot of things and [as this answer on a question on StackOverflow pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151343/how-to-move-an-application-between-monitors-in-hammerspoon), it's pretty easy to achieve what you want with a simple Hammerspoon configuration.

Hammerspoon is not exactly an app, but it might still be interesting for some users.

```
-- From https://stackoverflow.com/a/58662204
hs.hotkey.bind({'alt', 'ctrl', 'cmd'}, 'n', function()
  -- Get the focused window
  local win = hs.window.focusedWindow()
  -- Get the screen where the focused window is displayed, a.k.a. current screen
  local screen = win:screen()
  -- Compute the unitRect of the focused window relative to the current screen
  -- and move the window to the next screen setting the same unitRect 
  win:move(win:frame():toUnitRect(screen:frame()), screen:next(), true, 0)
end)
```

Comment: +1 for Hammerspoon ... very useful tool.   Maybe should point out that one can also use win:moveOneScreenEast() and the like (there's one function for each direction). It's useful to bind arrow keys to effect the keyboard shortcuts.   http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.window.html#moveOneScreenEast

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using the free, open-source tiling window manager [Amethyst](https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst) using the "Swap focused window to (counter-)clockwise screen" shortcut.

[image]