# Is there a way to quickly teleport a window from one display to another?

Tags: display, macos

I have multiple displays at my workstation, and I'm looking for a way to quickly "teleport" a window -- whether it's full-screened or not -- from one display to another.

When I was on Windows, I used an application called [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) that allowed me to middle-click on a window's titlebar and [instantaneously move it to the next monitor](http://www.displayfusion.com/Features/WindowManagement/). I'm looking for something similar to that.

It is possible to do this in Mavericks?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-a-window-from-one-monitor-to-another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net)

BetterTouchTool allows you to set a trigger to move a window to a second monitor, such as the one below:

[image: Trigger: Doubleclick Window Titlebar; Predifined Action: Move Window to Next Monitor]

<sup>Trigger: Doubleclick Window Titlebar; Predifined Action: Move Window to Next Monitor</sup>

Alternatively, a mouse button, keyboard shortcut, Apple Remote, Magic Mouse or trackpad gesture could be set up as the trigger.

### [Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate)

Slate is an extremely customisable tool that allows you to set window layouts/positions through keyboard shortcuts. Combining this with a BTT gesture, you can create a gesture-driven window movement tool for free!

> Slate is a window management application similar to Divvy and SizeUp (except better and free!). Originally written to replace them due to some limitations in how each work, it attempts to overcome them by simply being extremely configurable. As a result, it may be a bit daunting to get configured, but once it is done, the benefit is huge.

Comment: Sweet, this does what I'm looking for. There are a few restrictions on how this works, though: 1) The displays must be at the same resolution. 2) This doesn't work for full-screened windows.

Comment: @NickChammas Slate might be useful to you :) (See edit)

Answer (score 1):

It's not identical to DisplayFusion, but I've been using [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) for quite awhile now to manage windows between my non-Retina 15" MBP and my 27" Thunderbolt:

> With Divvy, it’s as simple as a single click and drag in the Divvy interface and your window will be resized and moved to a relative portion of the screen. If that seems like too much work, you can go ahead and create as many different shortcuts as you’d like that resize and move your windows.

Other 3rd party window managers for OS X include Witch, SizeUp, Breeze, and Cinch - here's a relatively recent review of several: http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/20-mac-window-management-utilities/

There's no similar built-in functionality in any OS X release, including Mavericks.

Comment: Too bad Mavericks doesn't include this. Divvy doesn't seem to do it either, though.