# Any key board shortcut to move application to another workspace in MacOS sierra?

Tags: keyboard, window-manager, alfred, bettertouchtool, spaces

I want my applications to be moved between workspaces with **only keyboard** in MAC OS SIERRA

Is it possible to move application to next workspace by

- any open source free tools ?
- any [alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com) workflows?
- using [bettertouch](https://www.boastr.net) tool

This is possible in ubuntu via compiz-plugins-manager software or just using awesome unity hud :) [more information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98872/move-window-to-right-left-workspace-shortcut)

As there are possible duplicates of this question mentioned below in the comment section and none of them have answers which works with only key board.

My question is whether the software utilities mentioned above alfredapp, bettertouchtool can be extended somehow to move applications between workspaces ?

Comment: It's unclear from your question exactly what you're trying to achieve - whether you want to move one window temporarily to another Space, whether you want that app to always open in that Space, whether you need to do this frequently & programmatically, or simply as a one-off arrangement that you will then stick to.

Comment: Potential duplicates are therefore - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-a-window-from-one-monitor-to-another?rq=1 so right now I'm voting to close as 'unclear' rather than a duplicate.

Comment: @Tetsujin I want to move app to the another space :) I have edited the question and regarding the duplicates , I have specified what exactly I need.