# Any Script to move windows from one monitor to the other

Tags: display

MacOS has an annoying bug that is completing a 10 year anniversary: If you have multiple displays, the contents of displays that are not the main one, are switched after coming from sleep.

This annoys the hell out of me.

Is there any application or script I can run to move windows on display 1 to 3 and vice-versa?

In my case I have 2 HDTV used as displays 1 and 3 and the main system, an iMac, is displays 2 in the middle.

thanks.

Comment: It's not actually a bug, it's an issue with the communication from the screens. If they are compliant, they should be remembered after sleep, or even a shutdown or reboot. If they were monitors, I'd suggest new cables or use DP instead of HDMI etc… but as they're TVs, they're probably [badly] designed to do it that way, computer sleeps, TVs switch to standby & lose the connection. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-a-window-from-one-monitor-to-another

Comment: There are reports on the web of macOS doing this to monitors too. What is DP? Sorry but macOS should not depend on an external device to do their part. I consider this a bug because I never saw this problem until High Sierra.

Comment: DisplayPort. It has to depend on the peripheral to do its part - otherwise how does it deal with a correctly disconnected monitor? if the monitor cannot differentiate & the Mac ignores it, your windows would stay off-screen. I've been using dual external monitors for probably 25 years - sure, something will occasionally jink [if I boot my windows machine the screen momentarily 'thinks' about its connection to both computers & will hiccup] but the vast majority of the time everything behaves.