# Keyboard shortcut or script to move full screen applications to another screen

Tags: keyboard, applescript, mission-control, fullscreen

I have four physical displays and like using applications in full-screen mode. While working, I typically have around 10 apps running in full-screen.

I frequently to rearrange the full-screen windows, moving them from one display to another by switching to mission control mode and then dragging and dropping the windows.

**Is there a way to do this using a keyboard shortcut or an Apple script?**

To clarify: I would like the app windows to remain in full screen mode at all times. Tools like Better Touch Tool, [recommended in another post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-a-window-from-one-monitor-to-another), only work with apps that are not in full screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, the post that is linked in the duplicate notification does *not* answer my question. My question is moving apps that are in full screen mode from one display to another. I am already using Better Touch Tool, which is recommended in the duplicate post, but that only has options to move apps around that are in window mode, not full screen.

Comment: If that's an important differentiator then you should [edit] your question to indicate remaining in full-screen mode is a requirement.