# How can a bring the windows of an application on the primary display?

Tags: display

For some reason my Air still uses its own LCD when the lid is closed, so that I often find that an apps windows are all on a display that I cannot see.

Is there any way of bringing them to the primary display without randomly clicking and dragging in the hope of hitting a title bar?

Answer (score 1):

Although the issue is rather strange, you can always take a look at some of the utilities suggested in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9659/115) stack exchange question. I personally use SizeUp so I'm able to move windows from one display to the other at will (something I do fairly often).

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > “Displays” prefpane > “Gather Windows” button at the bottom right corner.

[image: Displays System Preferences]

You can access the Displays prefpane faster by hitting <kbd>alt</kbd> and the function key that changes display brightness (exact name depends on your model, so I won't give any here).

Comment: Gather Windows only fetchs the monitor windows ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/360551/97777 ). Does it do more for you?

Comment: Thanks for the `Alt` hint. I've been using Quicksilver and typing `displays` blindly!

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor Oh sorry, I replied from memory, since I don't have any external screen to test with at the moment  :(  I really thought it gathered _all_ windows. Well, I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this, since I remember having had the problem, but then I can't find out without having test material. Sorry for the misleading answer!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that at one time it did gather all windows, as just the prefs ones are pretty useless, but ho hum.

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible to do using [Hyperdock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/). The preview windows that show up when hovering an application in the dock can be dragged out to wherever you'd like them. This also works across spaces.