# Remembering window position/size

Tags: macos, window-manager

At work, I have a 27" iMac with a 2560 x 1440 display. I have my windows all laid out as I like them.

On Fridays, I telecommute, using my Macbook Pro (1440 x 900) to connect to my work iMac using screen sharing. I use [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/indexSRX4.html) to change the resolution of the iMac to 1440 x 900. I then rearrange all of my windows to the new resolution.

I have [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/) and it helps in positioning the windows, but it does not support any mechanism for remembering groups of window positions and sizes.

Is there any alternative program that will allow me to configure my windows for 2560 x 1440 and save the sizes and positions for all of them as a group, then reposition them for 1440 x 900 and, again, save them as a group? Then on Fridays I will only need to tell the application to lay the windows out for 1440 x 900 and on Mondays for 2560 x 1440.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice application, [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/), that seems to do exactly what I need. I'll try it out this next Friday when I telecommute.

Comment: Did it work as expected? Also, can it work as "set and forget", or does it need constant manual configuration?

Comment: It works as expected, but I have not been using it much. I find that I rarely need to access my desktop Mac when I telecommute. I sync all the code I am working on between my iMac and Macbook Pro hourly, using Chronosync. When I work at home, I usually just work on the Macbook locally. As to "set and forget", its pretty much hands off. When I change resolutions, most of the windows reposition themselves correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can also go the Unix way and use an `.Xdefaults` file in your home directory. The syntax for the file is [here](http://xwinman.org/resource.php).
This should work on OSX too, by following these steps (taken from [here](http://forums.macworld.com/index.php?/topic/82432-xdefaults-for-mac-os-x-terminal/)):

> You can just make your own .Xdefaults file in a text editor and save it to the root of your home directory. However, since Apple's X11 does not look for it (it doesn't look for a .Xresources or .Xdefaults - you can name your file either one), you will need to point to it in your .xinitrc file.
>   use a line like xrdb -load $HOME/.Xresources in your .xinitrc file to load the .Xdefaults (or .Xresources) file you create.
>   P.S. if you don''t have your own custom .xinitrc file in your home directory, X11 will use the one in /etc/X11/xinit. You can just copy this one to your home directory (rename it as .xinitrc) and edit it rather then the default copy.