# Which App saves and restores window size/position on relaunch of an app?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, window-manager

Is there an app that saves (when I quit the application) and restores the window size and position of an application the next time I start it?

I found apps like Optimal-Layout, Breeze and Simple Window-Sets but all of these apps only give the option to save states for specific apps or globally.
What I would need is an app that saves the size and position of a window by its title.

For example:

I use iTap mobile RDP quite often. The application starts up with a little window showing the bookmarks I've created. Once I double-click on one of the bookmarked sessions the actual RemoteDesktop window appears. But the application always opens it at the upper left corner of my main monitor. I have to move the window to the second monitor every time I open a RemoteDesktop session. I've seen the same behavior for a lots of apps.

I would like to have an app that recognizes the title of the window and moves it to the position where I closed it the last time.
I would also like to avoid manually clicking something in the menu-bar or keyboard shortcut to restore a windows position. It should be some kind of "Window Watcher" which checks a windows title when its created and restores the position and size.

Does anyone know an app like this?

Comment: does this one help? 

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41022/remembering-window-position-size?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have to hit "Restore" manually even though "Restore Windows as applications are launched" is checked in the settings. I tried to link the window as the FAQ recommends but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score -1):

Ask the developer of iTap mobile RDP to add that as a feature.  Normally it is up to the application to keep track of its own windows.