# Freeware for tiling windows

Tags: software-recommendation, window-manager, utilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)

I've seen many, many utilities for resizing windows (BST, Moom, Divvy, SizeUp...) but I wanted to know if there were any available for free. Most of these utilities have a free trial, but I'd expect there's at least *one* available completely free.

So, is there one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) is a freeware application mainly for defining custom gestures of trackpads and Magic Mice, but it also has the ability to tile windows.

[image]