# Is there a window tiling app that snaps to other windows' edges rather than predefined screen areas?

Tags: software-recommendation, applications, window-manager

All window tiling apps I've seen are designed to make windows snap to preset screen areas, such as "the left half of the screen" or even "this size of rectangle specified with a grid." Is there one that would let me do, say, this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update in 2018:

### Rejoice, this is now an OS feature!

Try dragging your window slowly against another one, you'll encounter some resistance. You can use this to line them up quite easily.

I can't remember for sure when they added this, but I believe it was in OS X v10.12 Sierra.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [this Wiki question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9659/9495), and see if any of the answers meet your needs.

In particular, this one looks interesting:

[Zooom/2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/11594/9495) - "Magnetism. If you like snapping windows the the edges of the screen or other windows (as in many X window managers), you will love this."

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work on OS X Lion. :-(

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the developers front page says it has since July 2011?

Answer (score 1):

[Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/index.html) provides the snap to edges you are looking for, but I don't think it's good enough to do the total window arrangement you are looking for.

[SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) by the same provider as Cinch provides the ability to quadrant your screen, but these are more precise full quarter, rather than the different sized windows you have.

Comment: From what I can tell of both of those, they don't have quite the versatility I'm looking for.

Comment: Thats what I expected; personally Divvy is good enough for me, but you are looking for something that is a hybrid of all three products.  I don't know if it exists.

Comment: I don't need that, really, just any one of those *plus* the ability to snap to other windows.

Comment: Flexiglass, ShiftIt, Moom, HyperDock - they all basically copy windows 7 Aero Snap and snap to screen edges, not window edges.  You are likely out of luck here, but maybe someone will pull through.

Answer (score 1):

## [BetterSnapTool](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12)

Just like BetterTouchTool this app by Andreas Hegenberg is a very feature rich and highly customizable windows management tool.

- You can **either snap or use shortcuts** for predefined areas.

  Window snapping can be customized for each corner and and side (except bottom).
- You can define **snap areas** for *any* sort of window position and dimension.
- Shortcut behavior may be customized depending on application.

[image] [image]

[image]

Comment: It sounds like while this would let me customize it, it would be snapping to, for lack of a better term, custom presets rather than on-the-fly window edge snapping. Is this true?

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder I'm not sure what you mean by on-the-fly window edge snapping, but yes, this is tool offers customizable snapping presents.

Comment: I mean, for example, if there's a window of a random size in a random place, will I be able to snap another window to the edge of it, regardless of where they are on the screen?

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder Ok, now I understand :) That degree of flexibility is not yet possible with BetterSnapTool. But therefore it's only $1.99