# Snap/Maximize function has stopped working. What could be wrong and how can I fix it?

Tags: macos, window-manager, system-settings

Forgive the poor title.  I don't know what this feature is called.  I'm using OS X Lion, and there is a feature that I use all the time with my Thunderbolt display.

Specifically, if I grab the title bar and drag it to the top-center of my display, it expands the window size to the full size of my display.  If I drag the title bar to either the left or right of the screen, it fills 50% of the display, on that side.

All of a sudden, this functionality has disappeared.  I haven't been playing around with my computer preferences, either.

Is there a chance that I've hit some type of keyboard shortcut and accidentally cut it off?  Or, is there some preference setting (which I've tried my hardest to find) that I can check to see if this functionality has been cut off?

**UPDATE**

This is my first Mac.  It was purchased by my company for an iOS project that I've been given to complete.  My boss had setup some aspects of the machine before he passed it off to me-- I doubt he would have installed a third-party app because that's not how he works.

I did, however, install a third-party app that I used to make a few minor sensitivity tweaks to my magic mouse.  I know that app was a bit of over-kill for me, but I may have set some feature in it.

The odd thing is, I don't recall keeping that application, nor can I find it in my app folder.  Oh well.  Thanks for the helpful tips.  I'll restart and see if that helps.

It's unbelievable how much you can miss such a simple feature until it's gone.

Comment: I don't believe that behavior (equivalent to Windows's Aero Snap) comes out-of-the-box in OS X... Could there by some third-party extension or app you have (or had) installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is not a feature provided by OSX.**

You must have an extension installed  which adds this feature. e.g. BetterSnapTool or BetterTouchTool.

Maybe everything is fine and the applications just crashed. Then I'd try to log out and back in.

Also see [this list of window mangement tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9659/13414) to check if you have such an application installed.

- check for such an application in `/Applications` and `~/Applications`
- check *System Preferences → Other*

Answer (score 2):

This isn't built into Mac OS X.  You probably had a third-party addon you were using to emulate Windows' *Aero Snapping* feature.

There are *many* of these utilities, but the first one that comes to mind is [*Cinch*](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/).

Doing a quick search in the Mac App Store brings up quite a few titles that do this, including HyperDock, BetterSnapTool, DoublePane, Divvy, and Split Screen.  You probably have one of these on your computer, and somehow your startup item got lost.