# How to arrange two windows easily to left and right side? v2

Tags: window-manager

This question was [asked in 2012](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50330/how-to-arrange-two-windows-easily-to-left-and-right-side). I know that the solution is in upcoming version of OS X (fall 2015), but until then... is there any similar *internal* function to arrange windows in Windows-OS-like way? It is hard to believe there are not...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a new feature for the next OS X release: [El Capitan](http://www.apple.com/osx/elcapitan-preview/)

So I would suggest: wait for El Capitan :)

Comment: Windows has it for ages. I can't believe we should get this function for the last time in this fall :(

Comment: For ages = Windows 7 = Since 2009 :)

Comment: Nop, much earlier...

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built in way yet. You must use an application like cinch or use what was suggested in your linked question (BTT). As you have just shown, this has all ready been asked.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [Spectacle app](http://spectacleapp.com/) if you don't want to pay. It works pretty well, and you get a lot more out of it apart from just arranging windows side by side - you also get different sizes, and ease of moving between different monitors.