# Is there a way to combine two fullscreen windows into a split view window with Automator/AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, automator, split-view

I'm currently making a workflow in which I need to combine two windows into a split view window (the feature from OS X El Capitan). I'd there any way to do that with AppleScript?

Comment: If you use the record feature and press and hold the green button to get split view, I can tell you from experience that all you'll do is get ordinary full screen. I haven't tried recording opening two windows in full screen, then going to mission control and dragging them onto each other - see if that does the trick. In AppleScript, the former would be telling System Events to either select full screen from the menu bar or to hit its keyboard shortcut, but I haven't played around with it long enough to see what it can do with Mission Control.

Comment: Assuming you want something like the picture below, I believe what you need is creating a Service (system shortcut) that will: 1) find out your display resolution size 2) resize the frontmost window to cover half of the screen 3) position the window at the left side (0,0). And another shortcut to do the same for the right side (half, 0). Is this acceptable for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need a real fullscreen or are you trying to achieve something like this?

[image]

There are dozens of apps to do this so one of them will have AppleScript or key shortcuts. See:

- [How to arrange two windows easily to left and right side?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50330/how-to-arrange-two-windows-easily-to-left-and-right-side)
- [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)

Comment: Please do not downvote unless you have a proper reason. I would paste the picture in the comments if I could. As soon as the OP answer I will delete the question.

Comment: Hey Mateus - Some people are really strict and get highly agitated when an answer isn't a literal response, but I've upvoted and chosen to keep this. It moves the discussion forward in a very real manner. If you wanted to explain how to accomplish this given the situation you diagrammed is actually what the OP intended, I'm sure you'll get a lot more up votes. Don't forget - one up vote equals 5 down votes for answers.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and comprehension @bmike.

Comment: I ended up using ShiftIt to achieve this effect. I had the automator script use keystrokes to position the windows.

Comment: @user192958 thanks for the feedback, Apple should copy Windows once, just for a change.