# How to split app screen on my Mac?

Tags: macos, window-manager, split-view

I can reduce the size of pages to make multiple of them fit on my screen, but then they are never oriented properly :( Is there a way to actually split my screen as a command on my MacBook Air? I imagine that would line the pages up automatically.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, Lacy. I've added the tag window manager since many operating systems add these to handle arrangement of windows. If you search for popular questions in that tag, it might get you bountiful suggestions on how to manage windows on macOS.

Answer (score 4):

The supported Apple way of using split-screen for El Capitan onwards is documented at https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204948 in the section titled 'Use two apps in Split View'. It works nicely for apps that support it. The most up-to-date docs for Mojave are at https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/use-apps-in-split-view-mchl4fbe2921/mac

You can hold and drag the green maximise button of a window to one side of the screen to 'lock' it in position, then select another window to fill the other side. The same functionality is also available in Mission Control (ctrl-up arrow).

I'm not aware of a command that will do what you require, but it's possible using the GUI gestures.

Comment: The app BetterTouchTool can actually automate the long-click + drag motion, and you can assign this action to a macro. In BTT the action is called `Open Native OS X Split View for Window`, and supports both left and right sides of the screen. Choosing the app for the other half of the screen requires using the mouse, however.

Answer (score 2):

While as mentioned in the other answer, [Split View](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204948) feature available in OS X El Capitan and later lets you use two apps side-by-side.

However, that approach comes with certain limitations. The apps need to be in full-screen mode, there can be only two apps side-by-side, and both of them share half of the screen each.

You can use a 3rd party app that lets you quickly and easily align app windows. [Divvy](https://mizage.com/divvy/) is one such (paid with free trial) app that lets you easily manage app windows. It lets you configure a keyboard shortcut which gives you control to quickly and precisely set frontmost app window layout.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Divvy is available for download on the Mac App Store:

- [Divvy - Window Manager](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id413857545)

Free trial can be downloaded from the app homepage:

- [Mizage - Divvy](https://mizage.com/divvy/)

**Note**: No affiliation whatsoever with the developer of the app. I find the app useful in my workflow and use it on a regular basis.

Comment: Divvy is the one I recommend or get for people that want serious automation in their window management. Getting started with [side by side arrangement tools is nice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50330/) and the [massive list](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/) has some other gems in it.

Comment: All good suggestions, I use [Magnet](https://magnet.crowdcafe.com) myself. I refrained from listing 3rd party tools in my original answer to avoid complicating it, and without assuming the OP's needs beyond the basics.