# What software is available changing the default maximize button behavior in this video?

Tags: macos, window-manager

The still from [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZ-bgcJ6fQo&t=3m53s) (see image below) shows non-standard window maximization control options. Upon mouse hover on the `+` in the normal close, minimize, maximize controls (top-left of each window), a pop-up bubble is shown.

[image]

How can I enable these maximization options for my Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/). Very handy app for various window management.

[image: Moom screenshot]

The site has a general options list as well for the window management category at: [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)