# How do I move a window vertically above the menu bar?

Tags: macos, window-manager, menu-bar

How can I move a window so that the title bar of the window is above the menu bar?

I've tried using AppleScript…

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    set position of windows to {-100, -100}
end tell
```

…and whilst the `x` variable works, moving the window partially off-screen, the `y` doesn't, moving the window up to the menu bar and no further.

I've also tried Keyboard Maestro:

[image: Move Front Window to Position]

…but have the same problem: the `x` value works but the `y` does not.

<sup>This question is related, but opposite: [How do I move a window whose title bar is off-screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71112/how-do-i-move-a-window-whose-title-bar-is-off-screen)

I want to be able to *cause* the title bar to be off-screen.</sup>

Comment: — do you need the titlebar, and is this for all windows, or one in particular?

Comment: @l'L'l No, I don't need the title bar — I specifically don't want it ;) Just one window, but the ability to change the window if necessary (don't mind changing the code each time). I literally want to replicate the glitch shown in the [screenshot of the linked question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bZLLe.png), but on purpose, on demand :)

Comment: Ah yes, I'm familiar with that bug, although it's been a while since I've seen it. I think the key to achieving this might be creating your own glitch in this way. Do you recall when it happens?

Comment: @l'L'l I've had it once ages ago, when I was switching resolutions, but haven't been able to reproduce it.

Comment: Does Finder actually allow this really without bugging ?

Comment: @Matthieu Not quite sure what you mean — it's a bug, but I want to recreate it.

Answer (score 2):

Finder does not allow this as a general rule. Sometimes a glitch can make this possible, but relaunching Finder usually rectifies it. There's currently no known way to actually get this to happen as a desired behavior, sorry.

Comment: And luckily it doesn't! I remember a window opening above my Desktop in OS 7, it was a major pain to get it back in place!

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, more a 'don't try this, it doesn't work'

... one thing **not** to do is try changing which of 2 screens ought to have the menu bar - unless you want to spend 10 minutes putting all your windows back in the right place

Comment: I don't know why this was languishing with zero points: this is actually very good advice. It seems such a simple thing to try … until you have to recover from it.

Comment: Thanks for the late upvote :) It gave me chance to spot & fix my typo ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1) Download and build [Megazoomer](https://github.com/ianh/megazoomer), or use this [binary](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34314323/megazoomer.bundle.zip)
2) copy `megazoomer.bundle` to `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/` (you need [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) pre-installed)
3) restart app that you want to maximize
4) press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or choose Window -> Megazoom

Window will be maximized and placed above the menubar so it will take 100% of screen space without actually entering fullscreen mode.

Here is a really big TextEdit.app for your enjoyment (it doesn't support fullscreen out of the box)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R43o4.png

This plugin will do nothing to Carbon-based applications, since SIMBL will only inject code into Cocoa applications.

Comment: SIMBL is really outdated. Using such technology on current operating systems may cause problems.

Comment: Use [EasySIMBL](https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL) then

Comment: I can't get this to work. I have EasySIMBL and it works fine with other SIMBL bundles, but not megazoomer. The menu option doesn't show and the keyboard shortcut doesn't do anything either. Furthermore, I'm not sure this can do what I need anyway? Can a zoomed app then continue to be moved up?

Comment: No, window can't be moved up any further. Megazoomer works fine for me on 10.9.3 with EasySIMBL.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to get a window fullscreen (not showing the menubar) is to either go to fullscreen mode or write your own Application using CoreGraphic (like programming a game).

So the Apple window handling (integrated in the OS) doesn't impact cause the Application is drawing it selfs via the graphic driver and not via the OS.

Comment: I don't want an app resizing, just moved up (behind or on top of) the menu bar.

Comment: what do you mean with on top of? really above in z-axis or in y-axis? if you mean in y-axis that's not possible if you mean in z then either use the built in fullscreen mode (so the menubar disapears) or as i said you need to rewrite the App so it draws it selfs direct to the screen and doesn't use the os to draw it's content. if the app uses the os to draw it's content the os draw method will also prevent the app from  it's content over the menubar (i really hope it's clear what i tell you this time!)

Comment: I don't mind if it's in front of the menu bar or behind the menu bar, providing it is moved vertically upwards, beyond the menu bar, [as per the screenshot in the linked question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bZLLe.png).

Comment: This won't work and is s bug of Filezilla i think and in my opinion seeing only half of the App doesn't make sens either. I really can't see any possible Situation were i would need an app to act like this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. System Preferences>General
2. Click Automatically hide and show the menu bar.
3. The menu bar will disappear.
4. Drag your window to where you want it.
5. Uncheck Automatically hide and show the menu bar.