# quick resize app to half of window on Lion

Tags: macos, mac, ui

I am not a long-time Mac user and could find the answer.
So on Win7 there is a built-in feature when you click Win+← the window resizes to fit half of the screen and sticks to left.
Is there something similar on OS X?

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Spectacle ([github](https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle), [homepage](http://spectacleapp.com/)) is free, and works fine for me.

Comment: This one seems very close to what I want. Thank you!

Comment: Contemporary choice

Answer (score 5):

There are lots and lots of similar window management apps available, the one I like to use and recommend is called [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/).  Sounds a stupid name, but it's short for *Move and Zoom*.

Amongst various other functions (lots more, like edge snapping etc), it allows you to:

> Move your mouse over the green zoom button in any window, and Moom's mouse control overlay will appear ... [allowing you to]:
>
> - Move & Zoom to Full Screen
> - Move & Zoom to Left Half
> - Move & Zoom to Right Half
> - Move & Zoom to Top Half
> - Move & Zoom to Bottom Half
> - Revert to Original Dimensions

[image]

Keyboard shortcuts are also available and customisable:

> Keyboard mode allows you to do everything you can do in mouse mode, and more. It's all controlled by the Keyboard section of Moom's settings window.
>
> Once set up, you can use the keyboard to zoom windows to full/half/quarter-screen sizes, move them (while optionally confining them to the display) around, send them to another display; grow and shrink them, center them, and revert them to their pre-Mooming dimensions.
>
> After pressing the keyboard mode trigger key you define, an onscreen overlay appears. While the overlay is visible, you can use easy-to-remember keys (e.g., the arrow keys, plus Return, Tab, and Space) to control the frontmost window, instead of having to memorize tons of outlandish key combos.
>
> If you want a reminder as to your defined shortcuts, you can display a cheat sheet (enabled in Moom's Settings) along with the overlay:
>   [image]

So essentially, yes, you can replicate the feature diretly, with the same keystroke, only with plenty more options.  Moom isn;t free, but it's not particularly expensive either.  Plenty more window managers are available that do similar, and even cost less.  This is just my recommendation.

Comment: This looks nice. Will also give it a try tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Check out this Q&A also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x

Answer (score 3):

To emulate this from Windows, check out BetterTouchTool.

Comment: Thanks, checked it earlier today. It is okay, but seems too clumsy.

Answer (score 3):

I was directed here when asked the same question to google in 2020.

The solution in Catalina is to hold **Option** when hovering on the green windows button.
You'll be able to choose which half of the screen to bound the window.

[image: move a window to a side of a screen]

Comment: In Big Sur, this requires selecting a second window for the opposite side of the screen. I'm looking for a solution to only resize my current window.

Answer (score 1):

[Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) has a free trial, and is about $14 if you would like to get ride of a window that pops up and asks whether you want to buy the software. It allows you to customize different keyboard shortcuts to different window configurations.

Answer (score 1):

In 2021 you could use [rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/) since spectacle is no longer actively maintained.

Follow link for details, install with homebrew `brew install --cask rectangle`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of these: BettersnapTool or BetterTouchTool or Hyperdock