# Open Preview in full page view

Tags: pdf, preview

Whenever I open a PDF that is of ordinary DIN A4 format, the Preview window is oriented such that I can only see the upper half of the PDF. What I would like to have is a setting where I can define that every PDF is opened such that
- the full page is displayed
- the window is resized to reach vertically from the top to the bottom of the screen and
- horizontally has half screen size and that 
- the window is placed in the right half of the screen.

Can I define these settings somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

In 10.8 and later (but not in 10.7) there is a preference for the default view mode:

[image]

I don't know any way to change the default size or position of windows, but you can use an application like [Slate, ShiftIt, or Moom](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x) to assign a keyboard shortcut for resizing a window to fill the right half of a screen.

Comment: Skim seems to remember window position and size as well as display settings, great!