# A window manager that re-sizes and re-arranges ALL the windows for a given application with one keyboard shortcut?

Tags: window-manager

I have done research on Ask Different to see if this has been posted and to the best of my knowledge nothing this specific. I reviewed [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x) but that question is more general.

So imagine that I have 10 (or more) Evernote windows and I want, with one shortcut,  for all of them to be resized to half the monitor to the left. And then I have 6 terminal windows and want them all resized to a quarter screen to the upper right (different shortcut).

PS: What I currently use is SizeUp and it works great BUT in the case of the 10 Evernote windows, I'd have to use the keyboard shortcut 10 times.

Comment: This is hardly an answer but, out of the mentioned [list](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x), Slate, Moom and Flexiglass can save layouts/snapshots which is what you're looking for in a window manager. Essentially, you position windows the way you want and save a snapshot which can then be restored on the app's menu icon or shortcut.

Comment: I see what you're saying, my only thing is that the windows would not have constant titles (in other words, they would be different windows) so it would make it harder to pre-define a set, does that make sense?

Comment: It does. Window tiling really. The [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) website says: "Save Your Window Layouts - After laying out your windows as you wish, create a new Arrange Windows Custom Control, and click the Save Snapshot button. This will save the layout—size and location—of all opened windows (optionally not saving obscured windows). Later, when you want your custom arrangement back, type the keyboard shortcut, or activate the saved layout via Moom's menus". I think it operates on the open windows and doesn't rely on a specific window title.

Comment: Also check [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/). It can save and restore window layouts from different apps.

Comment: Megadroid, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for not dropping the subject! 

It sounds like having this question "officially answered" as by stack exchange process would be way helpful for other people. Do you want to paste your comment as an answer and I can declare it answered?

Comment: You're right, Carlos. I didn't post it as an answer before because I didn't test the app. I will add a more elaborated answer with a quote by Matt, Stay's developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/), I think it does what you want. Just launch your desired apps and store all open windows. You can then restore them on Stay's menu bar icon, with a shortcut key or have them restored automatically, when you launch each of the apps in question, or change displays.

I emailed Matt, Stay's dev and this is what he had to say about automatic restoration when launching apps and window title pattern matching:

> Stay does indeed have an option to restore windows when launching apps. It’s the checkbox labelled "Restore Windows as applications are launched” in Stay’s preferences window.
>
> Stay does its best to restore windows that it hasn’t seen before, but which are similar to windows that have been stored in Stay. When you store a window in Stay, it actually stores a set of attributes that it can use to identify that window, rather than a reference to the specific window that’s being stored. So if Stay sees another window that has the same identifying attributes, it will restore that window with the same size and position.
>
> There are situations where this approach doesn’t actually work all that well in practice though, and as such, Stay has a feature designed to help with this called window title pattern matching. There’s documentation on this feature available here:
>
> http://cordlessdog.com/stay/documentation/window-title-pattern-matching
>
> The basic gist of it is that you can control how Stay identifies your windows by telling it how to identify windows by their titles. The simplest use case is to set a pattern of .* (period asterisk) on a stored window, which will make that stored window match all of an application’s windows.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time, Megadroid, this is pretty useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use AppleScripts like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set b to bounds of window of desktop
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell windows of process "Terminal"
    set position to {(item 3 of b) / 2, 0}
    set size to {(item 3 of b) / 2, (item 4 of b) / 2}
end tell
```

You can assign shortcuts to scripts with [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/), [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com), or [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en).

Comment: Yeah, I may consider this at some point... Stay (the provided answer) does the job indeed but is pretty buggy at this time. It also seems to be pretty slow.