# Change default Preview window size?

Tags: terminal, pdf, preview

I'm working with LaTex and I'm using a text editor that, when I compile LaTeX files, runs a script to open the compiled pdf in Preview. The trouble is that Preview opens in the same default dimensions every time, which covers up other applications I have open.

It's not a huge deal, but it would be nice to have Preview open flushed right and as half the width of the screen every time. Since I'm opening and closing it so often, moving it and resizing it every time gets really annoying.

I realize this isn't a built-in option for Preview, but is there any way of doing it using Terminal or otherwise? I've googled around and haven't found any satisfactory answers yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this question: [What window management options exist for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)

My recommendation, if you want it to be fully automatic, is to use Slate.

[Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate) is no longer in active development, but it still works and is highly customizable. Put this code in a `.slate.js` file in your home directory:

```
var rightHalf = slate.operation("move", {
   "x" : "screenSizeX/2+screenOriginX",
   "y" : "screenOriginY",
   "width" : "screenSizeX/2",
   "height" : "screenSizeY"
});
slate.on("windowOpened", function(event, win) {
    if (win.app().name() === "Preview") {
        win.doOperation(rightHalf);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This .slate.js didn't seem to work on my end. Did I make a mistake? I don't know javascript, so I don't know if there's a syntax error.

In any case, I found a slightly less optimal, but working, solution. It's an app called Spectacle that binds certain keys to window configs, one of which is what I want for Preview. Worst coming to worst, I can just use that every time Preview pops up.

Comment: @gdavtor: I think we just found a bug in Slate. It's strange, but apparently you have to use `doOperation` or it won't work.

Comment: Very odd... I still can't get it to work.

Comment: @gdavtor: Are you sure you enabled accessibility for it?

Comment: Yes I just made sure. It isn't even throwing errors when I put gibberish in the .js file.

Answer (score 0):

You might also look into iSnap and Moom.

They're window manager applications. You can set preferences to snap windows to a particular location and or size & shape. Better Touch Tool also has a version of this functionality. These apps provide shortcuts essentially to having windows go where and how you want them to be displayed.