# Disable window snapping to top on move to second monitor/display

Tags: macos, display, window-manager

This annoying behavior started happening in 10.8 or 10.9 and I'd like to turn it off and make it never ever happen again.

What happens is that when dragging a window from one display to another, when I let go of the mouse button on the second monitor, the window doesn't stay where I left it upon mouse button release, but instead it snaps to the top of the screen where I did not position it.

Does anyone have any idea how to disable this annoying setting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not happening to me (I'm on Yosemite, but I remember it worked OK on earlier versions too). Maybe You have some kind of 3rd party software for window managment?

Comment: No 3rd party window management.  Can't switch to Yosemite and IMO, it's really really ugly and would prefer not to.  My windows that are being moved are being moved to/from a Thunderbolt display onto or off of a 15" retina display.  It may only happen with windows that are larger than the display they are being moved on to.  Just tested in Safari and it sucks.

Comment: read this post for possible solutions http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9659/46541

Answer (score 3):

Very annoying indeed and it's getting worse. The situation I am in is trying to view webpages in different screen widths. As the browser edge gets closer to other windows, Mac now thinks it must "jump to and hold it there" interrupting my process of expanding the page through every pixel width.

There is no setting to manage this yet, however, holding +alt while you scale or move windows dismisses the feature. The very nice bonus of dismissing the 'feature' with alt is how much video/CPU time it took to implement this nuisance is released back to your use. The dragging and re-positioning now becomes much more responsive and smooth rather than just jumping around the screen. It's now a habit to just hold alt as I resize any window on the screen.

Comment: side note: as you hold +alt to increase the width of the window, it will expand the opposite side to the screen edge as you expand, and collapse with you as well. (like a mirror).  This is the desired result for me, but might not match everyone's preference.

Comment: When you say hold `+alt` do you mean the `option` key? I've tried this on macOS 13.5 and doesn't seem to make any difference. As soon as the window I'm moving is about a quarter of its height on mac screen (my set-up is main screen above mac screen) it gets pulled into that screen.