# Moving the focused window to the bottom/top monitor with a shortcut

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, display, shortcut

Short version:  Is there a program that can move the focused/active window to the bottom/top monitor with a keyboard shortcut?

---

Long version:

Sometimes I need to move a window to the bottom/top, in my case between monitors 3 and 4 and between monitors 5 and 6:

[image]

I use [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) to move a window to the left or right monitor:

[image]

But it doesn't have the option to move a window to the monitor up or down.

[SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) has the same limitation:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the pointer. This thread is dreadfully broad though :-/

Comment: true - but it's the canonical collection

Answer (score 3):

## [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/)

You can:

- Move & Zoom to Full Screen
- Move & Zoom to Left Half
- Move & Zoom to Right Half
- Move & Zoom to Top Half
- Move & Zoom to Bottom Half
- Move & Zoom to Top Left Quarter
- Move & Zoom to Top Right Quarter
- Move & Zoom to Bottom Right Quarter
- Move & Zoom to Bottom Left Quarter

Define size and position and assign a shortcut.

[image]

Use a predefined shortcut and then use arrow keys to move the window.

[image]

Use a shortcut to move the window to another monitor.

[image]

For the record, Moom is usually 10$, but now is 5$.

Comment: Thanks but can Moon move a window from monitor 5 to monitor 6 with a keyboard shortcut for example? From what I can see most features move the window within the same monitor.

Comment: Can move a window to the monitor on the left, on the right, on the top or on the bottom. I update mi answer with an screenshot.