# Is there a tool or scripting approach to change the arrangement of displays?

Tags: macos, applescript, display, window-manager, system-settings

I move my monitors around a bit during the day. Specifically I rotate them or move my laptop to different positions. Each time I have to open up System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement and make the corresponding changes.

I'm looking for a tool or AppleScript approach for quickly setting a displays arrangement so I can quickly switch to proper arrangement.

Note I am not looking for a window management tool (plenty of those listed in [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)).