# Any ideas why Mavericks is slowing down due to BetterSnapTool?

Tags: macos, automation

I use BetterSnapTool to resize my windows with keyboard shortcuts. Since upgrading to Mavericks, after I've used my computer for 6-12ish hours, scrolling and moving things around the screen using the trackpad becomes sluggish and stutters. When I close BetterSnapTool, it fixes the issue, and it stays fixed until I relaunch.

Any ideas what is causing the issue? Is there an easy, low overhead way to automatically quit and relaunch BetterSnapTool every 4 hours or so?

Comment: My personal resolution: I switched to Spectacle, as explained here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x/66936#66936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answers the second question about how to automate restarting BetterSnapTool. Since I haven't experienced the issue described and have no second-hand explanations, I can't answer the question of *why* this is happening.)

Here is a quick and simple AppleScript I whipped up that works for restarting BetterSnapTools:

```
tell application "BetterSnapTool"
quit
end tell

delay 2 -- Wait for BetterSnapTool to close

tell application "BetterSnapTool" to activate
```

If you want to set this to automatically run every, say, 6 hours I think your best bet is to create a Launch Daemon using `launchd`. A quick presentation of this approach can be found [here](http://www.splinter.com.au/using-launchd-to-run-a-script-every-5-mins-on/). For more information, check [the entry on creating Launch Daemons in the apple developer's library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

You said "low overhead", which I took to mean using only methods native to OS X. If you're fine with third-party software, though, this [GUI application for `cron` (the precursor to `launchd`) scheduling](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7486/cronnix) seems promising (but I haven't tried it so can't be certain).