# Replacement for MercuryMover

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, software-recommendation, window-manager

It looks like my favorite OS X "window management" app, MercuryMover, is becoming abandonware. I'm looking for a well-supported alternative. I like MercuryMover because it is keyboard-driven, has a HUD that shows me the dimensions and position of the window I'm moving, and has a standard preferences screen for adding custom sizes and positions instead of a text-based configuration file.

Any suggestions for an alternative?

Comment: what alternatives did you look at ?

Answer (score 1):

The site has a general options list as well for the window management category at: [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x)

For your specific requirements of keyboard, HUD and non-text preferences, I would select either divvy or moom. The former is one I've selected for several clients and they have enjoyed it and adopted it easily. Moom is also awesome and has some nice gestural / mouse / trackpad workflows.

- http://mizage.com/divvy/ ----- [Divvy on the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/divvy-window-manager/id413857545?mt=12)
- http://manytricks.com/moom/ ----- [Moom on the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moom/id419330170?mt=12)

I linked above to the free trials and web sites first with a Mac App Store link to follow.

Answer (score 0):

BetterSnapTool is quite handy!has all kind of configuration options and works just like windows 7-10 management, where you snap app windows on the side to or to the top to maximise the current application window and has a menu bar icon where you can access all kinds of options.I think this is the website for more info, but App Store is more informative.[bettersnaptool](https://www.boastr.net/bettersnaptool/)

Comment: Why is it? handy

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.