# Keyboard shortcut to partition screen

Tags: macos, display, shortcut, window-manager

I've recently started using a Macbook on a new job (macOS 10.15), coming from a Windows 10, and then more a Ubuntu background.

A feature that both Windows 10 and Ubuntu had was the ability to have an application use half of a given display, by pressing the <kbd>special</kbd> + <kbd>⬅</kbd> or <kbd>⮕</kbd>. Windows 10 can also split a screen again into quarter by using <kbd>special</kbd> + <kbd>⬆</kbd> or <kbd>⬇</kbd>

This feature is particular useful for using large monitors, where I might display my text editor and a browser side by side.

[macOS does have split screen functionality as mentioned here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948), but there is no mention of keyboard shortcuts.

Is there an equivalent keyboard shortcut function for this on macOS?

Comment: You could try purchasing a little app called Magnet from the Mac App Store. It’s extremely useful allowing you to split screen, drag windows to each half/quarter of the screen and has some customisable shortcuts. Have a look: https://apps.apple.com/au/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12

Comment: @AVelj that actually looks quite good - I might give it a go

Answer (score 1):

Yes Apple allows split screen with a vertical slider or divider out of the box.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948

There are many awesome window manager that automate many grid layout, are flexible and very friendly to key shortcuts. I like moom and divvy in particular.

- [Replacement for MercuryMover](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187188/replacement-for-mercurymover)
- [Is there a way to exactly position a window?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303908/is-there-a-way-to-exactly-position-a-window)
- [More than two windows split view](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228192/more-than-two-windows-split-view)

Comment: Hi - Yes I did see the apple split screen -though that help page has no mention of keyboard shortcuts.