# Permanently Enlarging the "Open File" dialog box in Yosemite

Tags: macos, finder

Whenever I open a file in any application I'm presented with the standard "Open" dialog box which I find to be frustratingly small (less than 50% in each dimension on my 11 inch screen). I can enlarge it to a more generous size, but the new dimensions don't seem to be made permanent, so next time I open a file the standard small-size dialog is shown.

Is there a way to permanently resize this dialog box?

Comment: It seems the size was saving until 10.10.1 or 10.10.2. At least Script Editor has a menu option to save the size of the Open dialog, but that's the only one I know of.

Comment: The open dialog is actually provided by the system these days, for sandboxed applications. There are fewer options for controlling its presentation.

Comment: browse true this : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x

Comment: Have you tried this? Copy and paste the command into Terminal and hit return: defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSNavPanelExpandedSizeForOpenMode '{"926, 639"}'

Comment: @MorganR that command fails with error `Could not parse: {"926, 639"}.  Try single-quoting it.`

Comment: @whitman Did you copy and paste the command? You should have ...OpenMode '{"926, 639"}' (with single and double quotes) as apposed to just ...OpenMode {"926, 639"}

Comment: @MorganR The command as posted does not work for me either: `2016-10-20 15:46:46.157 defaults[58937:6901206] Could not parse: {"926, 639"}.  Try single-quoting it.`

Answer (score 3):

I tested this with `TextEdit` and it does not remember the size of it's open dialog window. I tested it with `Script-Editor` and `BBEdit` and they both remember the size.

After reading something about another, maybe related situation, I tried this:

I resized the open dialog in `TextEdit` like it is described [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/12/08/resize-large-open-save-dialog-windows-mac-os-x/) (second screenshot).
[ *which is: hold the SHIFT-key and click into the right side of the dialog and start dragging it* ]

And when I do that this way, `TextEdit` remembers the size, also between relaunches.

So may be this is possible with all applications you want to remember it's open dialog size? It's not a general solution but a workaround. If it does the job it may be a pretty useful one.

I got the idea to try this from here
(second screenshot): http://osxdaily.com/2014/12/08/resize-large-open-save-dialog-windows-mac-os-x/ and I found that site with a google query containing the title of your question.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 10.10.3, what OSX version have you tried this on?

Comment: 10.10.3. It works here when I do it like in the screenshot shown. And it persists, it's still as big as I resized it yesterday (in TextEdit).

Comment: To test it, you could try to delete TextEdit's preferences (if you are willing to start with the default set) and try that SHIFT-CLICK-DRAG again (to delete the prefs, run this code in a Terminal.app window:  "defaults delete com.apple.TextEdit" (without the quotes). Quit TextEdit before executing.

Comment: Is your TextEdit connected to iCloud? I noticed that this trick seems to work on all apps except those which use iCloud. So maybe the dimensions for the iCloud-enabled open dialog are hardcoded instead of being read from the `NSNavPanelExpandedSizeForOpenMode` like regular open dialog boxes.

Comment: No, I don't use iCloud.

Comment: Ah yes, that could be, kinda like shared prefs.

Answer (score 1):

This **may** help you.  You can set the open dialog to always open in expanded mode - it still will not store the last screen coordinates however that you used - however - always being in expanded mode would help on a 11 inch screen

Open the **Terminal**

and type:

```
defaults write -g NSNavPanelExpandedStateForSaveMode -bool TRUE
```

You may need to restart the finder

```
killall Finder
```

Answer (score 1):

Click the bottom right corner, hold down Option, drag the window to what you'd like.  10/10 times, it saves this X/Y setting.

Comment: I thought so too... this seems to no longer be working very unreliably in Big Sur. Kind of driving me nuts. So maybe more like 7/10 times?

Comment: well, yeah, looks like a known annoyance in 11.1

Answer (score 0):

Not a 'system fix' but using a 3rd party app, [DefaultFolderX](http://stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) (approx £30 UK, with 30-day trial period) you can take charge of how you deal with Open/Save file-pickers.

I don't use half of what it's capable of, yet still find it worth the outlay, & have done for 15 years.

My prime use of it is to navigate to any open folder on the desktop, but resizing & remembering file pickers is just one of its features.

*no affiliation, just a satisfied customer*