# How do I do a Windows-Left or Windows-Right on Apple?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I want to have 2 windows next to each other using a shortcut. How do I do that?

Comment: Have a look at divvy - http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=divvy Unless I'm mis-understanding your post - it's the tool for the job.

Comment: Also, are you more interested in the functionality or the key combo? What have you already tried?

Comment: 13,99 EUR for something which is free on Windows? Seriously? Any other options? Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: I just want to put one window on the left half of my screen and one window on the right half of my screen.

Comment: Any of those free versions recommendable? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x/9686#9686

Comment: This is nice: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/66936/164712

Comment: Now I only need to know how to put it in "Autostart". I found already the user option in the system preferences but the program is not listed under programs. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

On the top left The Green Button for full screen / maximize have three ways:
short click -> app goes to full screen, creates a new desktop
long click -> app goes half full screen and you can choose from open windows for another half for the screen (that's a new desktop workspace too practically)
option+click -> app goes "old style maximize"

If I get your question well, the "long click" is what you are looking for. Only works in El Capitan 10.11, this is new feature. For older versions there were plugins to emulate Aero snap

Comment: I got 10.11.2. Long-click does not have any function here. I am using Spectacle now. I disabled Spaces btw. because I do not like or need that. Option-Click does the same as Click.

Comment: "I disabled Spaces btw."

That's why it is not working actually. It needs spaces