# Does MacOS have a keyboard shortcut for moving an individual window to another monitor?

Tags: macos, display, shortcut, window-manager

What's the MacOS equivalent to Windows' keyboard shortcut to move AN individual window to another monitor? Let's assume a dual-monitor setup.

The specific Windows keyboard shortcuts I'm hoping to find equivalents to are the following:

- Move Window to Left Monitor:
  <kbd>[image: Windows Icon Symbol]</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>
- Move Window to Right Monitor:
  <kbd>[image: Windows Icon Symbol]</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
- Maximize Window:
  <kbd>[image: Windows Icon Symbol]</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>
- Minimize Window:
  <kbd>[image: Windows Icon Symbol]</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

Comment: macOS doesn't 'think' in monitors it thinks in desktops/spaces. One monitor can have many spaces & one space can be on either monitor. I'd say this would need a 3rd party tool.

Comment: Catalina has that option, but no shortcut to it, It is under menu Window-> Move to Builtin Display or Window-> Move to External Display. But no shortcut either pressing option/command/shift with all combinations. But possible via acessing the menu with keyboard arrows or via mouse click. There is "minimize" using Command+M

Comment: As a Windows to MacOS user, I ended up using [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com) to mimic those Snap features

Comment: @ernie, wow didn't realize there was vocabulary which captured the concept. Window snapping, I like it. [How-To: Enable Aero Snap-like window snapping on your Mac](https://9to5mac.com/2016/05/06/how-to-enable-aero-snap-like-window-snapping-on-your-mac-video/) It also jibes well with vector graphic drawing lingo as in Adobe Illustrator's `Snap To Grid` feature.

Comment: this is _partially_ answered in the mega-thread https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/66936/133605

Comment: Related: [Move a full screen app to second monitor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/253759/55584)

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there's a default key shortcut, but if you look in the Window menu, there is a menu item there "**Move to** `name of display`".

[image]

So you could create shortcuts yourself in **System Preferences > Keyboard** for the command that is visible in each display.

[image]

Comment: Note that this option is disabled if the Window is currently full screen.

Answer (score 3):

Spectacles has been discontinued.

I use the app **Magnet**, downloadable from the [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12), which has the "Next display" capability using:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>

Comment: [Rectangle](https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle) is a successor to Spectacles.  It has an OSS version and a paid version with more features.

Comment: Rectangle explicitly states, though, that "Rectangle doesn't have the ability to move to other desktops/spaces"

Answer (score 1):

At least with macOS Big Sur and newer, there is a built-in option for moving to another monitor:

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

OR

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

Please note: the arrow direction **doesn't always match the display orientation** like it does on Windows.  That is, you ***might*** have to use the **right arrow key to move it to the left side monitor**.  But, it's easy enough to try the left arrow key first, if that doesn't work, try the right arrow.

The correct key to use is indicated in the Window menu:

[image: Move to other monitor shortcut]

Comment: On my macOS Ventura 13.4/13.5 systems it only requires `Control` + `→` (or `←`) ... `Option` + `Command` are not necessary.  If the arrow direction doesn't match the display arrangement go to System Settings, Displays and use the "Arrange..." button.

Comment: For me (macOS 14.1.2), `Control` + `→` (or `←`) switches to the next or previous desktop but the currently active window stays where it was. Where do you set this?