# Is it possible to add a third app to split view?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I want to open 3 apps in split view. Where one is on the left side while 2 are stacked over on the right side. Do I need another tool for it or can I do it in macOS itself?

Answer (score 2):

[Magnet](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12) for macOS has builtin keyboard shortcuts for resizing a window to left third, centre, or right third of the screen, left and right halves, and any of the four quarters in the corners of the screen. Makes realigning windows pretty simple. Can of course use the second desktop functionality in macOS along with this too. BetterSnapTool is similar but I don't think it can do thirds.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the full screen apps functionality. Full screen apps only supports a maximum of two windows.

For more than two apps/windows, you'll need to arrange the windows themselves as you desire. There are a number of apps that can help with this, as discussed at [What Window Management Options exist for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9659/37797).